# Trying to access properties of the containing object in php

Tags: php, class

After hours looking for solutions and patterns, it's time for me to ask the pros.

I'd love to order my object in a logical hierarchy, but still want to be able to access properties of the parent object. A simple example how I'd love to have it work...

```
    class car {

       public $strType;  // holds a string
       public $engine;   // holds the instance of another class

       public function __construct(){
           $this->type = "Saab";
           // Trying to pass on $this to make it accessible in $this->engine
           $this->engine = new engine($this);
       }

    }

    class engine {

        public $car;

        public function __construct($parent){
            $this->car = $parent;
        } 

        public function start(){
            // Here is where I'd love to have access to car properties and methods...
            echo $this->car->$strType;
        }
    }

    $myCar = new car();
    $myCar->engine->start();
```

What I won't achieve is that a method in engine can access the 'parent' car properties.
I managed to do so like this, but I believe that is very very ugly...

```
    $myCar = new car();
    $myCar->addParent($myCar);
```

From within the addParent MethodI would be able to pass the instance on to the engine object.
But that can't be the clue, can it? Is my whole idea queer?

I don't want engine to inherit from car because a  car has lots of methods and properties and engine has not. Hope you get what I mean.

Hoping for hints,
Cheers Boris

Comment: Why does the engine contain a car? The car should only contain an engine.

Comment: You have access to them by `->parent` (well, their public ones), by `$this->car->strType` (NOT `$this->car->$strType;`)

Comment: Car is not parent of engine though. Car only contains it. You cannot access with ->parent. Well, I think the problem is about the logic. Engine shouldn't tell car that it started. Car should tell engine to start. Engine should return saying that "hey, i have started mate. let's get the hell out of here", etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Wrikken mentioned, the correct syntax would be `echo $this->car->strType;`

`type` does not seem to be a member of `car`, but if you changed it the line to

```
$this->strType = "Saab";
```

Then the statement in question should now echo "Saab"

Though I think good practice here would be to not have the engine class contain a car object, just the car class should contain an engine object. And the properties would be better off as `private`. So you could have a car method like

```
public startEngine() {
    $success = $this->engine->start();
    if(success) {
        echo "Engine started successfully!";
    } else {
        echo "Engine is busted!";
    }
}
```

Where `engine::start()` returns a boolean.

Comment: You both were right. It was a typo...
echo $this->car->strType; is the thing.
But that still does not work. I agree that having a car within an engine doesnot make much sense. The point is that I want to be able to access anything in my object tree from every other branch in my car object...

        $myCar->doors->left->open();
may need to use
        $myCar->cabin->light->switchOn();

Comment: Did you actually set `strType` like I mentioned in my answer? And why does "door" need to turn the light switch on, when you can just call both statements in the main update loop, using the same car instance. It's more efficient, and you will save yourself much hassle.

Comment: Narf. Works. Thanks. :)

Did you mean that I should place all public methods in the car object?

The car is just a simplification. I have a cms api with loads of entities with sometimes the same properties and methods. So I wanted to organize the public methods in some object hierarchy.

        $myPage = $myCms->pages->getByGuid("A870A2BF75F64677864F2AE9B8090475");
        $myElement = $myPage->elements->getByGuid("D47F9D48256840A1BABA784E39C4680D");

In fact the elements->getByGuid needs the guid of the page, too.
So this is why I intended to access back uplwards in the hierarchy.

Comment: Cool, np. Feel free to check 'accepted answer' :) And no, I was saying keep the methods the way they are, and you can just call `$myCar->doors->left->open();` *and* `$myCar->cabin->light->switchOn();` (in the same code block) instead of having former *call* the latter within itself. Does that make sense? I could be wrong and be misunderstanding your program..

Comment: I guess I really need to do this in my case. Allthough I'm still absolute with you that a motor should logically not contain a car. :)