# How to access properties of a nested PHP object?

Tags: php, json, stdclass

I'm trying to do an web app which people can see their status in League of Legends, but I don't even know how to do some things. 
I've got this class:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [player] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => xxxxxx
            [name] => yyyy
            [profileIconId] => 627
            [summonerLevel] => 30
            [revisionDate] => 1422798145000
        )
 )
```

and im using this php code:

```
<?php 
        $summoner = 'yohanbdo';
        $summonerdata = $leagueclass->getsummoner($summoner);
      ?>
```

I want to take only the id, name and profileIconId and show it. I don't know how to do this.
PD: My english isn't that good so thanks you all for the edits.

Comment: These are just objects, use the -> operator to access the values.
For example $obj->player->id;

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to access properties of the containing object in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846230/trying-to-access-properties-of-the-containing-object-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Weird, I was just looking that Riot API a little while ago.

I feel like you're pretty new to this type of notation, so I'll try and be quick but concise with my explanation.

What you have there, as Gerifield stated, are objects. You access their properties by using the `->` operator. For example, if I assume that the object `$main` is what you're `var_dumping` out, then you could simply get the objects like so:

```
$main = json_decode($some_json_string);
//Now that we have the object set, we can deal with the properties.
echo $main->player->name; 
//This will output the player name. 
echo $main->player->id;
//Will output the player ID.
```

Notice in each case that since the `player` key of the `$main` object is *also* an object, it's properties must be accessed via the `->` operator.

However, you could also simply use associative arrays by passing the second parameter to json_decode, like so:

```
$main = json_decode($some_json_string,TRUE);
echo $main['player']['id'];
echo $main['player']['name'];
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thank you dear for answer, but I can't do it work. Im actually using http://harings.be/lolclass/ instead the official Riot API. Could you add me one skype? It will take just 5 minutes. User: "wesley.bdo". If you can't, thanks anyways.

Comment: I don't use Skype, sorry.